# ElasticSearch and Kibana represents diferente Datetime

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Folks, 
Someone can help me to understand which parameter I  need to change in Kibana to show the same Elasticsearch hour?

In File : `17-07-18 11:08:59`
In ElasticSearch : `2018-07-17T11:08:59`
In Kibana :  `July 17th 2018, 08:08:59.000`

I just did the default indexes mapping inside the Kibana and choose the `data` field to represent the time.

I changed the `dateFormat:tz` parameter

Tks for help

Comment: I resolved the issue changing the `dateFormat:tz`in Kibana to UTC .

Comment: [Credits to Elastic discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-represents-diferente-datetime/140401/5)